# How would i make a Python program to a exe that would work on all devices with a .mp4 file?

Tags: python, mp4, py2exe, python-vlc

I want to convert a .py file to a .exe file that would work on all devices (or just all desktops if all devices isn't possible).

I tried to use py2exe but that doesn't work because it doesnt take the .mp4 file with it.

```
import vlc

# Create an instance of the VLC player
instance = vlc.Instance("--no-xlib")
player = instance.media_player_new()

# Set the video as the media to play
media = instance.media_new("yaai.mp4")
player.set_media(media)

# Set the video to loop
player.set_fullscreen(True)
player.play()

# Run the event loop
while True:
    pass
```

The .mp4 file is in the same folder.

Comment: checkout [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) `add-data` specifically.

Comment: @Tranbi Pyinstaller only works if the user hase the libary's installed.

Comment: That's not true. Where do you get this from?

Comment: i isn't? So it would just run on others peoples desktop without having the libary's installed?

Comment: Have you clicked on my link? "PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into a single package."

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pyinstaller with add-data.